# mouse following css tooltip example

Tags: css, tooltip

Can a css tooltip be made to follow the mouse like the javascript alternatives?

The reason I ask is because many javascript tooltips seem to take some time to load/render, and I've found no examples.

Can this be done?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, with CSS you can only give a tooltip a place in the viewport based on it's parent position or a position inside the viewport.

CSS doesn't know the position of the cursor.

So, you do need javascript to accomplish that, or be satisfied with the fact that the tooltip doesn't move along with the mouse pointer.